# load social button after mouse over?

Tags: social-networking, mouseover

I've visit some popular blogs these days I see that they actually using some kind of JavaScript code or something like `mouseover` that will load the social buttons after the mouse is pass the buttons or when they hover them.

Like this example.

This picture is before the mouse hover on,

and this one is after

[image]

and this one is after

[image]

so obviously they use some kind of code I want to know how can I make it for my Wordpress site. This will help a lots on site performance and Google will like this so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is what you're looking for my friend.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp